Why does ps jxf -u otheruser show my user processes?
The command ps jxf -u otheruser shows processes from user otheruser as well as my own user id.
Why is this?

The process selections made by x and -u options are cumulative: x selects all your processes, -u selects all the named user’s processes, and ps outputs all the selected processes.
To see only otheruser’s processes, run
ps jf -u otheruser

See man ps for details.
